# How does ARM Linux emulate the dirty, accessed, and file bits of a PTE?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, mmu

As per [pgtable-2-level.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable-2level.h), ARM Linux has two version of PTE; The Linux PTE and H/W PTE.  Linux PTE are stored on below a offset of 1024 bytes.

When handling page fault in `handle_pte_fault` various function like `pte_file`, `pte_mkdirty`, `pte_mkyoung`, get invoke with the version H/W PTE.

But actually ARM H/W does not support the dirty, accessed and file bit in its PTE.

My question is how does it check the dirty, accessed, file bit of a page on H/W PTE?  Ideally it should check those bit on Linux PTE which are stored below an offset of 1024 bytes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is how does it check the dirty, accessed, file bit of a page on H/W PTE?

TL;DR - they are emulated by taking a page fault on initial accesses.

The answers are given in [pgtable-2-level.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable-2level.h),

> The "dirty" bit is emulated by only granting hardware write permission
>   iff the page is marked "writable" and "dirty" in the Linux PTE.  This 
>   means that a write to a clean page will cause a permission fault, and 
>   the Linux MM layer will mark the page dirty via handle_pte_fault(). 
>   For the hardware to notice the permission change, the TLB entry must 
>   be flushed, and ptep_set_access_flags() does that for us.

To take the *dirty* case, the initial MMU mappings for page are marked read-only.  When a process writes to it, a page fault is generated.  This is the `handle_pte_fault` referenced and the main code is in [fault.c as `do_page_fault`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/fault.c#n236) and will call the generic `handle_mm_fault` which eventually ends at [`handle_pte_fault`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/memory.c#n3780).  You can see the code,

```
if (flags & FAULT_FLAG_WRITE) {
        if (!pte_write(entry))
            return do_wp_page(mm, vma, address,
                    pte, pmd, ptl, entry);
        entry = pte_mkdirty(entry);  /** Here is the dirty emulation. **/
}
```

So the Linux generic code will examine the permission of the page, see it is suppose to be writeable and call the `pte_mkdirty` to mark the page as dirty; the whole process is kicked off or emulated through the fault handler.  After the page is marked *dirty* in the Linux PTE, the ARM PTE is marked as writeable so subsequent writes do not cause a fault.

*accessed* is identical only both read and write will initially fault.  A *file* bit is also completely unmapped and when a fault occurs, the Linux PTE is consulted to see if it is backed by a file or is it a completely *unmapped* page fault.

After the hardware table is updated with new permissions and book keeping is done, the user mode program is restarted at the faulting instruction and it would not notice the difference, besides the time interval to handle the fault.

---

ARM Linux uses 4k pages and the ARM 2nd level page tables are 1k in size (256 entries * 4bytes).  From the **pgtable-2-level.h** comments,

> Therefore, we tweak the implementation slightly - we tell Linux that we have 2048 entries in the first level, each of which is 8 bytes (iow, two hardware pointers to the second level.)  The second level contains two hardware PTE tables arranged contiguously, preceded by Linux versions which contain the state information Linux needs.  We, therefore, end up with 512 entries in the "PTE" level.

In order to use the full 4K page, the **PTE** entries are structured like,

1. Linux PTE [n]
2. Linux PTE [n+1]
3. ARM PTE [n]
4. ARM PTE [n+1]

Four 1k items for a full 4k page.  These collections of pages must be managed per process to give each a unique view of memory and some information is shared in order to conserve real RAM.  The function `cpu_set_pte_ext` is used to change the physical ARM entries.  As each ARM CPU revision uses slightly different tables structures and features, there is an entry in the [*processor* function table](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/proc-fns.h#n23) that points to an assembler routine.  For instance, [`cpu_v7_set_pte_ext`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/proc-v7-2level.S#n62) is the ARMv7 or typical original Cortex CPU implementation.  This routine is responsible for examining the Linux flags and updating the hardware bits accordingly. As can be seen, the `r3` is written to `pte+2048` (offset from Linux PTE to hardware PTE) at the end of this routine.  The assembler macro [`armv3_set_pte_ext`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/proc-macros.S#n193) in **proc-marcos.S** is used by many of the older CPU variants.

See: [Tim's notes on ARM MM](http://elinux.org/Tims_Notes_on_ARM_memory_allocation)
         [Page table entry (PTE) descriptor in Linux kernel for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909101/page-table-entry-pte-descriptor-in-linux-kernel-for-arm)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but again my doubt and confusion is how does pte_write()  return true for a read only page ,which version of PTE checked by  pte_write macro, is it  Linux PTE or ARM PTE ??          in a same way pte_mkdirty  modified which entry Linux PTE or ARM PTE ?? because from handle_mm_fault  gets pte from pte_offset_map , it seems it return ARM PTE , please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Actually, those seem to be new questions.  I have updated my answer.  The magic you seek is `cpu_set_pte_ext`, which is like a C++ virtual function and is implemented differently for the variable ARM MMU bit layouts (new CPU types have extended features).  However, they are all common in writing to both the Linux PTE and the ARM PTE (+2048).

Comment: Linux only operates on the Linux PTE values.  Only when they are *committed*, does a `cpu_set_pte_ext` function get called which examines the Linux version and updates the hardware version.  For instance, [`set_pte_at`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable.h#n241) and a few other places where the PTE is initialized.