# page table walk in armv7 linux by S/W leads to which version of page table ARM PTE or Linux PTE

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, mmu

My question is in [handle_mm_fault](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arc/mm/fault.c#L133) function or any S/W page table walk.

```
pgd = pgd_offset(mm,address);
pud = pud_offset (pgd,address);
pmd = pmd_offset (pud,address);
pte = pte_offset_map(pmd,address);
```

Will the final computed pte be the ARM or LINUX version?

In armv7 supports 2 levels of page table; At the first level 4096 entries of each 4 bytes has an address for the second level. The second level has 256 entries of each 4 bytes. Linux has tweaked the page table to have 2048 entries of each 8 bytes in other words having two pointers to second level of page table having 512 entries placed contiguously. Linux PTE stored below these 512 ARM PTE.

So I understand that page table walk through in S/W will leads to ARM PTE only, but that is not correct Linux always operates on Linux PTEs?

Please tell me where I am wrong?

I Got the answer.
 I understood that, all these macro will leads to the Linux PTE only  , since the  L2 level page table of 4kb size and from 0th offset the linux pte0 starts and 1024th offset linux pte1 starts. while calculating pte_index it mask the lower 12 bits of PMD value thus PMD will always point to the start of page and there are Linux PTE stored.

Comment: See: [How does ARM Linux emulate...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943129/how-does-arm-linux-emulate-the-dirty-accessed-and-file-bits-of-a-pte), especially the 2nd half.  I might answer in a little while.

Comment: I want to create a  debugfs entry to duml the page table for a particular process. I have to walk the page table by the pgd_offset to pte_offset_map ... When I see the defination of these macro it leads me to belive that finally computed pte will be arm pte ..but as the emulation of Linux pte I looks like compued pte will be Linux PTE.I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the answer. I understood that, all these macro will leads to the Linux PTE only , since the L2 level page table of 4kb size and from 0th offset the linux pte0 starts and 1024th offset linux pte1 starts. while calculating pte_index it mask the lower 12 bits of PMD value thus PMD will always point to the start of page and there are Linux PTE stored.